# <th> and <td> are in different spots on my webpage

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm very new to web design and I'm practicing designing a website at my internship for this summer. I'm trying to make a `table` for a table on the right side and the bottom the classes are named "BroadCastSchedule" and "RightSearchBar" in the code.

I can't post the picture because this is my first post to stack overflow but if you run the code you can see the two sections of the table are very far apart and I can't get them to be together.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>Channel 14 Schedule</title>

  <div class="img">
    <a href="https://www.ctv15.org"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
  </div>

</head>

<style type="text/css">
  #navBar {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 75px;
    left: 200px;
  }
  
  #menuli {
    margin: 0px;
    max-width: 450px;
  }
  
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: gray;
  }
  
  h1,
  h2 {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 75%;
  }
  
  .searchBar {
    top: 200px;
  }
  
  .titleBox {
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    bottom: 75px;
  }
  
  .img {
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
  }
  
  .RecentlyWatchedBar {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 575px;
    left: 200px;
  }
  
  .searchTool {
    position: relative;
    right: 200px;
  }
  
  .videoLink {
    /*Change size where the video is linked*/
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
  }
  
  .RightSearchTable {
    position: relative;
    right: 75px;
    top: 100px;
  }
  
  .Calender {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -75px;
    right: 75px;
  }
  
  .BroadcastSchedule {
    display: table-header-group;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    right: 350px;
    margin-right: -200px;
    padding-right: -200px
  }
  
  #h1FontSize {
    font-size: 150%;
    left: 700px;
  }
  
  #h2Location {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  input {
    position: relative;
    left: 1000px;
    bottom: 25px;
  }
  
  table,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    left: 1000px;
    bottom: 500px;
  }
</style>


<body background="images/bg.png">
  <div class="mainItemsDiv">

    <div class="titleBox">
      <h1 id="h1FontSize">Channel 14 Schedule</h1>
      <h2 id="h2Location"><i>Local Government And Sports</i></h2>

    </div>


    <div id="navBar">
      <ul id="menuli">
        <li><a href="http://www.ctv15.org/" style="color: #707070"><strong>Main</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.ctv15.org/about" style="color: #707070"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
        <li><strong>Schedule</strong></li>
        <li><strong>Podcasts</li>
     <li>Search</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="searchTool">
     <input type="text" placeholder="search">
     <input type="button" value="Search">
    </div>

   </div>

   <div>

   <div class="videoLink">

    <iframe style="margin-top: -80px"width="657" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XxqcwGI6dOY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

   </div>

   </div>

   <div class="RightSearchTable">

    <table width="225"; height="580">
     <tr>
      <th>Show Search
       <p>Roseville High School Concerts</p>
       <p>St. Anthony Football</p>
      </th>
     </tr>

    </table>



   </div>
   <div class="RecentlyWatchedBar">

    <p style= "color: #707070; text-indent: 50px">Recently Watched</p>

    <p>
     <ul>
      <li><iframe style="margin-top: 0px"width="150" height="110" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XxqcwGI6dOY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
      <li><iframe style="margin-top: -80px"width="150" height="110" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XxqcwGI6dOY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
      <li><iframe style="margin-top: -80px"width="150" height="110" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XxqcwGI6dOY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
      <li><iframe style="margin-top: -80px"width="150" height="110" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XxqcwGI6dOY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
     </ul>
    </p>
   </div>

   <div class= "Calender">
    <table width="225"; height="225">
     <th>
      <p>Calender tool will go here</p>
     </th>
    </table>

   </div>



   <div class="BroadcastSchedule">
     <table width="250"; height="100">
      <tr>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Location</th>
       <th>Start Time</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Date Data</td>
       <td>Location Data</td>
       <td>Start Time Data</td>
      </tr> 
     </table>

    <!--
    <table style="width:650px; height: 100px;">
       <tr><td>Firstname</td>Eve</tr>
         </th>
         <th>Lastname</th> 
          <td>Eve</td>
         <th>Points</th>
          <td>Eve</td>
        <tr>
         <th>Eve</th>
         <th>Jackson</th> 
         <th>94</th>
       </tr>
    </table>
    -->


    </div>
  </div>
 </body>



</html>
```

Comment: Please only include the relevant code no one wnats to read all this. Also you can put a link to the picture if you need to show one.

Comment: Since you're very new to web design, I would advice against going things like putting a `<table>` directly in an element with `display:table-row-group`, until you know all the intricacies of such a move. Also, you can't have negative padding.

Comment: I would probably advice from putting `div` tags in the `head` tag as well... haha. You probably should look up some online html/css courses/tutorials.  I recommend Treehouse or CodeSchool.

Comment: ? They are separated in the markup.

Comment: I feel really dumb I figured it out shortly after I posted this, Thanks guys. Also, it was my first post ever on StackOverflow so sorry if it was confusing or redundant in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing table data instead of table row. Change this line in your css:

```
  table, td{
    //Do something
  }
```

To this:

```
  table, tr{
    //Do something
  }
```